# Excel formula calculating working hours depending on shift start and shift end

Tags: excel, formula

```
2/6/23 3:00 PM (Start Date and Time)
12/7/23 8:00 PM (End Date and Time)

11:00 AM (Shift Start Time)
8:00 PM (Shift End Time)
```

with this data i want to calculate the working hours, Start Date and Time is 12/6/23 3:00 PM but then he stop because he shift end at  8:00 PM (Shift End Time) then start again the other day with his shift is 11:00 AM (Shift Start Time) then completed it at 12/7/23 8:00 PM (End Date and Time)

answer should be 14hours

Comment: i create this formula but the answer 29hours

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2), ISNUMBER(B2), ISNUMBER(C2), ISNUMBER(D2)),
  IF(B2 < A2, "End time must be after start time",
    IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2) > 5, WEEKDAY(B2) > 5), "Weekend not allowed",
      IF(A2 >= INT(B2) + D2, 0,
        IF(B2 <= INT(A2) + C2, 0,
          MIN(B2, INT(B2) + D2) - MAX(A2, INT(A2) + C2)
        ) * 24
      )
    )
  ),
  "Invalid input"
)

Comment: Are you numbers always in same format i.e. as laid out above?

Answer (score 0):

As evaluating your formula the last part which does the real calculation has an error.

```
MIN(B2, INT(B2) + D2) - MAX(A2, INT(A2) + C2) ) * 24
```

try to replace with this

```
(IF(MIN(D2-C2,D2-A2+INT(A2))<0,0,MIN(D2-C2,D2-A2+INT(A2)))+IF(MIN(D2-C2,(B2-INT(B2)-C2))<0,0,MIN(D2-C2,(B2-INT(B2)-C2)))+(D2-C2)*(INT(B2)-INT(A2)-1))*24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MOD` function to pull out the time part of the datetime.

Example: Assume your data is as follows:

```
       A                       B
   1   02/06/2023 3:00 PM      =((A5-MOD(A1,1))*24)+((MOD(A2,1)-A4)*24) ~~> 14.00
   2   12/07/2023 8:00 PM
   3
   4   11:00 AM
   5   8:00 AM
```

In `B1` add the formula `=((A5-MOD(A1,1))*24)+((MOD(A2,1)-A4)*24)` and it will return `14`, the number of hours worked (i.e. 5 + 9).

Hope this helps